# I have been using a list for this, but what would be best in this situation?

Tags: html, css

I have been using a list to create this:

[image: contact list]

I'm not sure if this is best. This is my code:

```
<ul class="contact-info">
  <li>Phone</li>
  <li class="phone"><a href="tel:+1(111)555-1234">+1(111)555-1234</a></li>
  <li>Email</li>
  <li class="mail"><a href="mailto:email@yoursite.com">email@yoursite.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

I cannot seem to get it like the image though. As if I use inline or inline-block they all remain on the same line.

Please help! :)

Comment: Can you add your styles and combine your `html` and `css` in a code snippet for user-friendly reproduction and troubleshooting?

Comment: You could go for a [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine... You could be using an address tag or definition list for your contact information, and to spice it up you could use schema.org metadata.

And for your inline problem, you could simply divide them in two `<ul>`-s

```
<ul class="contact-info">
    <li>Phone</li>
    <li class="phone"><a href="tel:+1(111)555-1234">+1(111)555-1234</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Email</li>
    <li class="mail"><a href="mailto:email@yoursite.com">email@yoursite.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

### Definition list

A definition list is a list of terms and corresponding definitions. Definition lists are typically formatted with the term on the left with the definition following on the right or on the next line. The definition text is typically indented with respect to the term.

```
<dl>
    <dt>name:</dt>
    <dd>John Doe</dd>
    <dt>tel:</dt>
    <dd>01-2345678</dd>
    <dt>fax:</dt>
    <dd>02-3456789</dd>
    <dt>email:</dt>
    <dd>johndoe@someemail.com</dd>
</dl>
```

*Of course, in combination with `tel:` and `mailto:` protocols*

[Example of definition list displaying contact information](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/Techniques/working-examples/H48/ContactInfoDL.html)

### Address tag

The address element provides contact information for a document or part of a document. Information provided by address may include the names of the document’s maintainers, links to the maintainers’ Web pages, e-mail addresses for feedback, postal addresses, phone numbers, and so on. The address element is not appropriate for all postal and e-mail addresses; it should be reserved for providing such information about the contact people for the document.

```
<address>      
    UNIVERSITY INTERSCHOLASTIC LEAGUE<br>
    1701 Manor Road, Austin, TX 78722<br>
    Tel: (512) 471-5883 | Fax: (512) 471-5908
</address>
```

[W3C Address element](http://w3c.github.io/html/grouping-content.html#elementdef-address)

### Schema.org microdata for search engines

You could also take a look at schema.org microdata in order to style the way information gets displayed on search results...

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <h1 itemprop="name">Beach Bunny Swimwear</h1>
    Phone: <span itemprop="telephone"><a href="tel:+18506484200">850-648-4200</a></span>
</div>
```

[Adding Phone Numbers To Web Pages With HTML5 and Microdata](http://thenewcode.com/536/Adding-Phone-Numbers-To-Web-Pages-With-HTML5-and-Microdata)

[Schema.org](http://schema.org/)

Comment: You know what, so simple but didn't even think of doing separate lists! haha. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If there is no reason for the particular structure of your DOM, you could put the labels inside of the list item so that they end up on the same line:

```css
ul.contact-info {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.contact-info li span {
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #999;
}
ul.contact-info li a {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul.contact-info li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="contact-info">
  <li class="phone"><span>Phone</span><a href="tel:+1(111)555-1234">+1(111)555-1234</a></li>
  <li class="mail"><span>Email</span><a href="mailto:email@yoursite.com">email@yoursite.com</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think of putting it within the list before the <a> tags. I guess I could use a class selector on the span also. That's a good idea for sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [microformats](https://microformats.io/):

http://microformats.org/wiki/h-card

> **h-card** is a simple, open format for publishing people and organisations on the web. h-card is one of several open microformat draft standards suitable for embedding data in HTML.

```css
.h-card {
  text-align: center;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.h-card a {
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.h-card span {
  display: block;
}

.h-card .u-email:before {
  content: 'Email';
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.h-card .p-tel:before {
  content: 'Phone ';
  padding-right: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<p class=" h-card contact-info">
  <span class="phone p-tel"><a href="tel:+1(111)555-1234">+1(111)555-1234</a></span>
  <span class="mail u-email"><a href="mailto:email@yoursite.com">email@yoursite.com</a></span>
</p>
```

Comment: microformat is super interesting. I hadn't heard of that before. I will definitely look into this. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

I used this in the end but not sure whether it is very good code:

```
 <ul class="contact-info">
  <li class="info"><a href="tel:+1(111)555-1234">Phone &nbsp;<strong>+1(111)555-1234</strong></a></li>
  <li class="info"><a href="mailto:email@yoursite.com">Email &nbsp;<strong>email@yoursite.com</strong></a></li>
</ul>
```

Just put them on the same line and added an extra space with:

```
&nbsp;
```